# Will JTAG wipe internal memory on Galaxy sII?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, odin

I have hard bricked my phone by flashing wrong bootloader. My phone wont show any signs of life but warming of the back side.

I have some private photos, messages, etc  that i don't want the repair man see them. He said to me that when you JTAG the phone, all the phone memory contents such as ROM and internal memory are completely wiped. Is this true? Cant he recover internal memory sdcard before or after JTAG?

Please only answer if you are 100% sure

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean, "when you JTAG the phone"? JTAG is the name of a standard used by hardware debugging interfaces. Are you going to connect a hardware debugger to your phone's mainboard?

Comment: Yes, its exactly what you mentioned. However i dont have the hardware... The complete expression would be "JTAG unbreak recovery".My phone wont boot up and using such hardware a new rom/bootloader will be forceably installed to the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Your files even the deleted files Can be recovered even from dead phone with the help of JTAG or ISP Solutions !

**1 - Find or Locate Pinouts**

If your phone available pinouts for JTAG'ing you can JTAG otherwise you can relate to ISP pinouts if two option not available for your phone you can always chip-off and recover the DATA !

```
JTAG : ort-jtag.com
ISP  : emmc-pro.com
```

For the case of Galaxy S2 - You can JTAG or ISP Direct!

[image: image of JTAG pinouts]

**2 - Read the Full image of your phone !**

After reading the full image of your phone with the software mentioned above .
You can analyze the Dump and extract your private pictures etc..

**3 - Data Recovery** 
Data Recover : Autopsy ( Sleuth Kit )

Best Regards